# android display string

Tags: android, xml, string

I am trying to pass a string from one activity to another. I retrieved the information like this:

```
Intent openReadMail = getIntent();
String readfrom = openReadMail.getStringExtra("from");
```

Now I want to display this string on screen. I this xml TextView element:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

but I can't convert the string to a textview, is there a better way of doing this? thanks for your help guys!

Comment: One observation, your `TextView` should have a `layout_height=""` attribute as well, otherwise you may get an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a variable for your TextView and then set the text.

```
TextView fromtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.from);

Fromtxt.setText(readfrom);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the text of the TextView with the String you read in.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.from);
tv.setText(readFrom);
```